# I have configured buildserver of TFS 2013 in Remote PC. It shows following error in Event log

Tags: visual-studio, build-server, tfsintegrationplatform

Exception Message: TF30063: You are not authorized to access http://Server Name/tfs/Collection Name. (type TeamFoundationServerUnauthorizedException) Exception Stack Trace: at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Hosting.BuildMachine.StartOperation.End(IAsyncResult result, HttpRouter& router, TfsMessageQueue& messageQueue, List`1& processHosts, MachineLifecycleActivity& traceActivity) at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Hosting.BuildMachine.EndStart(IAsyncResult result) at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Machine.WindowsService.EndStartMachine(IAsyncResult result) Inner Exception Details: Exception Message: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. (type WebException)Status: ProtocolError Response Status Code: Unauthorized Response Status Message: Unauthorized Exception Stack Trace: at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpWebRequest.SendRequestAndGetResponse(HttpWebRequest webRequest, WebException& webException)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the port number of your sever, default is 8080:

```
http://ServerName:8080/tfs/CollectionName
```

Comment: Are you able to ping the TFS AT machine on this remote PC?

Comment: yes. it is possible to ping TFS AT machine on this remote pc where i have configured Build Server.

Comment: Is the account you install Build service a member of Project Collection Administrators group on TFS? Follow this article to configure build service: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee259683(v=vs.120).aspx